# creating multiple eth keys from one private key

Tags: wallets, private-key, public-key

I want to create multiple Eth public Keys from one private Key like exchange hot wallet

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, PrivateKey can only have a **single** PublicKey (For ETH ecosystem)

Private key is nothing more than random 256 bits (usually written down in hexadecimal format).

Therefore you can take you own private key and hash it with [keccak-265 algorithm](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html). The result will be another private key.

This process can be repeated as many times as you like. The final result will be a number of private keys that originate from the "original key"

NOTE: The downside of this is that loosing the original key will compromise the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but do what I want, it's different: I want to create a wallet that will have a public Key and a private Key.  We'll call him the master.  now when a user comes to register on my platform I will generate a public Key for him which must be attached to the master .  The objective is to be able to transfer the funds received by all the public Keys from a single private Key.  I think that's how CEX works

Comment: Interesting, I understand the concept, but I am not sure that is possible for EVM-compatible networks